# Can't find the error in my 25+5 clock with React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

There is an error somewhere but I can't find what or where it is. It used to work before but I don't know what happened exactly why it doesn't work anymore because nothing appears on my screen now.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.loop = undefined;
    this.state = {
      breakCount: 5,
      sessionCount: 25,
      clockCount: 25 * 60,
      currentTimer: "Session",
      isPlaying: false,
      loop: undefined
    }
  }
  
 handlePlayPause() {
   const {isPlaying} = this.state;
   
   if (isPlaying){
      clearInterval(this.loop);
   } else {
     this.loop = setInterval(() => {}, 1000);
   }
 }

  componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.loop);
  }
  
  convertToTime(count) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    let seconds = count % 60;
    
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? ('0'+seconds) : seconds;
    
    return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  }
  
  render() {
    const {
      breakCount, 
      sessionCount, 
      clockCount, 
      currentTimer
    } = this.state;
     
    const breakProps = {
      title: 'Break Length',
      count: breakCount,
      handleDecrease: this.handleBreakDecrease,
      handleIncrease: this.handleBreakIncrease,
    };
    
    const sessionProps = {
      title: 'Session Length',
      count: sessionCount,
      handleDecrease: this.handleSessionDecrease,
      handleIncrease: this.handleSessionIncrease,
    };
    
    return (
  <div>
    <div className="flex">
      <SetTimer {...breakProps} />
      <SetTimer {...sessionProps} />
    </div>

    <div className="clock-container">
      <h1>{currentTimer}</h1>
      <span>{this.convertToTime(clockCount)}</span>
      <div className="flex">
        <button onClick={this.handlePlayPause}>
          <i className={`fas fa-${isPlaying ? 'pause' : 'play'}`} />
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.handleReset}>
          <i className="fas fa-sync" />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}
  
const SetTimer = (props) => (
  <div className="timer-container">
    <h1>{props.title}</h1>
    
      <div className="flex actions-wrapper">
      <button onClick={props.handleDecrease}>
        <i className="fas fa-minus" />            
        </button>
      <span>{props.count}</span>
      <button onClick={props.handleIncrease}>
        <i className="fas fa-plus" /> 
      </button>
      
     </div>
</div>)

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik&display=swap');

*{
  box-size: border-box;
}

body{
  
  background-color: #006266;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  display:flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

.timer-container {
  margin: 20px ;
}
.timer-container h2{
  margin: 0;
}

.actions-wrapper button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.actions-wrapper span {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.clock-container {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 30px ;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}

.clock-container span{
  font-size: 50px;
}

.clock-container h1{
  margin: 0;
}

.clock-container button{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

I looked back the video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rz6XbrCqt0&t=1877s] of Florin Pop's 25+5 clock  a few times but still don't see where the error is. ChatGPT and several online JS validators didn't help either..

Comment: Can you tell us what error message did you find in the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found two mistakes, there might be more but I think you can correct it on your own.

1. The class component is missing a closing bracket. There should be a closing bracket above SetTimer
2. `isPlaying` variable is undefined inside the render function, it needs to be destructured from this.state in the render function

Corrected code

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.loop = undefined;
      this.state = {
        breakCount: 5,
        sessionCount: 25,
        clockCount: 25 * 60,
        currentTimer: "Session",
        isPlaying: false,
        loop: undefined
      }
    }
    
   handlePlayPause() {
     const {isPlaying} = this.state;
     
     if (isPlaying){
        clearInterval(this.loop);
     } else {
       this.loop = setInterval(() => {}, 1000);
     }
   }
  
    componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.loop);
    }
    
    convertToTime(count) {
      const minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
      let seconds = count % 60;
      
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? ('0'+seconds) : seconds;
      
      return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    }
    
    render() {
      const {
        breakCount, 
        sessionCount, 
        clockCount, 
        currentTimer,
        isPlaying
      } = this.state;
       
      const breakProps = {
        title: 'Break Length',
        count: breakCount,
        handleDecrease: this.handleBreakDecrease,
        handleIncrease: this.handleBreakIncrease,
      };
      
      const sessionProps = {
        title: 'Session Length',
        count: sessionCount,
        handleDecrease: this.handleSessionDecrease,
        handleIncrease: this.handleSessionIncrease,
      };
      
      return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex">
        <SetTimer {...breakProps} />
        <SetTimer {...sessionProps} />
      </div>
  
      <div className="clock-container">
        <h1>{currentTimer}</h1>
        <span>{this.convertToTime(clockCount)}</span>
        <div className="flex">
          <button onClick={this.handlePlayPause}>
            <i className={`fas fa-${isPlaying ? 'pause' : 'play'}`} />
          </button>
          <button onClick={this.handleReset}>
            <i className="fas fa-sync" />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
    
  const SetTimer = (props) => (
    <div className="timer-container">
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      
        <div className="flex actions-wrapper">
        <button onClick={props.handleDecrease}>
          <i className="fas fa-minus" />            
          </button>
        <span>{props.count}</span>
        <button onClick={props.handleIncrease}>
          <i className="fas fa-plus" /> 
        </button>
        
       </div>
  </div>)
  
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! now it is working again! I'm still new with React :)